# Ubuntu 12.04 GTA SA install with wine

Tags: games

i tried install GTA SA on ubuntu 12.04 (with the original cd and i don´t have a partion with windows) with wine. The installation goes well but when i tried to play, the play run until the second logo and then it´s stop and became black.
I don´t know if the problem is something concerne about the driver nvidia because in the section drivers adittional i don´t have any information. Plus i made the installiont in the right way (and tried many ways) so please help me!
(I have already play in this computer but when i have windows and i never had a problem plus i play wow with wine and it does ritgh)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe tell us what version of Wine you are using. Also on this page: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2599 it says Retail CD have Bronze badge, so maybe download patch and try again.